# How to modify list element?

Tags: python, list

I have two python lists:

```
name = ['Beijing']
alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

I need to add each element of  alphabet to the element in name such that output is :

```
new_name = ['Beijinga', 'Beijingb', 'Beijingc']
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Does the first list always have the single element?

Comment: `list(map(''.join, zip(name*len(alphabet), alphabet)))`

Answer (score 2):

You can try in the following example.

```
import string
name = 'Beijing'
new_nam = [name + item for item in string.ascii_lowercase]
```

Output:

```
['Beijinga', 'Beijingb', 'Beijingc', 'Beijingd', 'Beijinge', 'Beijingf', 'Beijingg', 'Beijingh', 'Beijingi', 'Beijingj', 'Beijingk', 'Beijingl', 'Beijingm', 'Beijingn', 'Beijingo', 'Beijingp', 'Beijingq', 'Beijingr', 'Beijings', 'Beijingt', 'Beijingu', 'Beijingv', 'Beijingw', 'Beijingx', 'Beijingy', 'Beijingz']
```

Answer (score 2):

In your example, you have only **one name**.
Assuming you will have **many names**, I have a solution (It would work for single names too) -

```
name = ['Beijing','QWERTY']
alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c']

new_lst = []
for j in name:
    for i in alphabet:
        new_lst.append(j+i)
```

**Result**:

```
['Beijinga', 'Beijingb', 'Beijingc', 'QWERTYa', 'QWERTYb', 'QWERTYc']
```

Or, you could use a **[list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp)** which is better and makes it easier -

```
new_lst = [j+i for j in name for i in alphabet]
print(new_lst)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have two lists of arbitrary size, you can use `itertools.product()` to do this quite easily:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> name = ['Beijing']
>>> alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> new_name = list(map(''.join, itertools.product(name, alphabet)))
>>> new_name
['Beijinga', 'Beijingb', 'Beijingc']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use string concatenation with list comprehension:

```
name = ['Beijing']
alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c']
new_name=[name[0]+x for x in alphabet]
print(new_name)
```

If there are multiple elements:

```
name = ['Beijing']
alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c']
new_name=[names+x for names in name for x in alphabet]
print(new_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
name = ['Beijing']
alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c']
new_name = [name[0]+i for i in alphabet]
```

Comment: This gives TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

Answer (score 1):

If you are a beginner at Python this code may help you.

```
names = ['Beijing']
alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c']

newName = []

for name in names:
    for letter in alphabet:
        newName.append(f"{name}{letter}")
```

Comment: Instead, you could append the final output without f-strings - `newName.append(name+letter)`